# How to find all and connect all available wifi signals using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, networking, wifi

I am working raspberry pi to find and connect all available wifi connections. How can I find and list all WIFI Networks available using python. Can we print all available wifi connections by using python sockets.  If sockets can't do this job then which library can we use to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one of the best modules for wifi manipulation in python is the wifi package.

`pip install wifi`

Simple use case is; (replace "wlan0" with your wireless device id)

```
from wifi import Cell, Scheme
list(Cell.all('wlan0'))
```

This will return a list of Cell objects. Each object will have the following attributes:

- ssid
- signal
- quality
- frequency
- bitrates
- encrypted
- channel
- address
- mode

For cells that have encrypted as True, there will also be the following attributes:

- encryption_type

To connenc to an AP;

```
cell = list(Cell.all('wlan0'))[0]
scheme = Scheme.for_cell('wlan0', 'home', cell, passkey)
scheme.save()
scheme.activate()

scheme = Scheme.find('wlan0', 'home')
scheme.activate()
```

for more info goto https://wifi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: The output is : <map object at 0x7fe9dbffdcc0>
How can I get it as string, wifi signal/device name?

Comment: how can I get SSID/ESSID printed on the screen as output?

Comment: `cells = Cell.all('wlan0')` then you can do `for cell in cells: print(cell.ssid)` and any other attributes mentioned in the list above

Comment: Its now working! Cool.
**Thanks dear for the help. :)** 
Is this exact thing possible with the help of socket ?

Comment: You can connect via sockets but I don't think it's possible to search AP's with sockets as it does not contain that functionality

Comment: For how to connect with sockets try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41516828/can-i-use-pythons-socket-module-to-connect-to-a-wireless-ethernet-host

Comment: Is there anyway to get the wireless device ids of the wireless signals available with  the help of wifi or socket?
As `iwlist scan` does in ubuntu.
I want to list all wifi signals available using python script. 
Is this possible at all?

Comment: the wifi module uses iwlist scan to gather its information

Comment: use `cell.signal` & `cell.quality` just try all the attributes

Comment: that shows just signal strength. I need to get the device id like in this:
`cells = Cell.all('wlo1') `
Is there any way to get the `wlo1 using socket or wifi. 
when in ubuntu terminal we run command `iwlist scan` :
The output will be:
**wlo1   Scan Completed :
_all information here_

**  I need the wlo1 
how can this information be extracted?

Comment: you mean you want your code to get the "wl01" name from within your code?

Comment: Yes **exactly**

Comment: so we can use another module called wireless from pypi but it doesnt work with python3 due to a function missing but you can use my version from my git hub (link will follow shortly) `from wireless import Wireless
wireless = Wireless()
wireless.interfaces()
`

Comment: grab the wireless module that works with python3 https://github.com/jamiejackherer/wireless

Comment: Error: 
`raceback (most recent call last):
  File "list_wifi.py", line 2, in <module>
    wireless = Wireless()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/wireless/Wireless.py", line 23, in __init__
    self._driver_name = self._detectDriver()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/wireless/Wireless.py", line 50, in _detectDriver
    compare = self.vercmp(ver, "0.9.9.0")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/wireless/Wireless.py", line 71, in vercmp
    return cmp(normalize(actual), normalize(test))
NameError: name 'cmp' is not defined
`

Comment: you have used the pypi version which does not work with python3 with adding a function called cmp() which is why I said you will need the version from my github or just add the cmp() function to Wireless.py

Comment: add `def cmp(a, b):
    return (a > b) - (a < b)` at the top of Wireless.py

Comment: I have downloaded your version from github. How can I install this package?

Comment: unzip the master.zip or if you cloned just enter the directory, then run `sudo python3 setup.py install` or `python3 setup.py install --user` for local install (your home directory)

Comment: **Thanks ** again ...
I am done. Got the device id. 
**Thanks** for your precious time dear.

Comment: how can I connect to a network as I am getting list of all available wifi signals. I am trying that `activate()` method, but isn't working properly. Maybe I am not using that method properly.

Comment: `cell = Cell.all('wlan0')[0]`
 `scheme = Scheme.for_cell('wlan0', 'home', cell, passkey)`
 `scheme.save()`
 `scheme.activate()`
How to use this code here?
`cells = Cell.all('wlo1')

for cell in cells:
    print(cell.ssid)

`

Comment: i am a bit busy but will get back to you asap

Comment: Okay bro.
What I am trying to do is:
First find and display all available wifi networks.
Second connect to one of the desired wifi network.
Third all these tasks should be done within a python program or that might be in python shell script.
Then send a message dumb message to that connected network, like what we can do using sockets.
This is what I am trying to do.

Comment: when I try cell = Cell.all('wlan0')[0] it gives TypeError: 'map' object is not subcriptable, how to solve this one, and where i need to pass the password for wifi, is it in passkey? And what is 'Home' there?

Comment: It seems the code for wifi has changed a little bit. Now `Cell.all('wlan0')` returns a map. So you can easily use `list(Cell.all('wlan0'))[0]` to index the map

Comment: @JamieLindsey python `wifi` module not support Windows?