# How to use scan() method from winwifi package

Tags: python, wifi

I'm new to python development, I would like to scan nearby available networks using python (on windows machine). I found out that using winWifi is an easy way to do it. But winwifi.WinWiFi.scan() returns a list of objects, how can I return the list of available SSIDs from a python file?
thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find all and connect all available wifi signals using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53246654/how-to-find-all-and-connect-all-available-wifi-signals-using-python)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I'm looking for a way to scan nearby networks using winwifi package, not wifi package

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the string output you can see the related class:
<winwifi.main.WiFiAp object at 0x0000016DBB11C5E0>

Which exists in source code here:
https://github.com/changyuheng/winwifi.py/blob/master/src/winwifi/main.py

So use:  obj.ssid  to access the ssid property.